# Error encountered on opening Queue Manager name = .... Reason code = 2354

Tags: c#, sql-server, biztalk, mq

First: I have two BizTalk applications. First one does polling from SQL server and send to an MQ queue, works fine. The second processes a file and uses a dynamic send port. In the orchestration I have updated **TOMQ(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address)= QueuePath;
TOMQ(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType)="MQSeries";** It grabs the file, processes it, sends the results to an output directory. (This works fine.) Then to MQ. MQ throws the error:  **Error encountered on opening Queue Manager name = .... Reason code = 2354.** I checked and it is getting the correct queue path, but fails.  Anyone have any suggestions. I've checked all I can think of.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://azurebiztalkread.wordpress.com/2018/03/31/biztalk-the-adapter-mqseries-raised-an-error-message-details-error-encountered-on-opening-queue-manager-name-xxxx-reason-code-2354/

Comment: Already hit that page. Like I said I have another application that hits MQ just fine. And when I change the port to a static port in this application, it also hits MQ just fine. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Update: I added a static port also going to MQ, prior to the dynamic send port and the message from the static port is written to MQ. Double checked the value to TOMQ(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address)= QueuePath; and it's correct as well as my transport setting.. Anyone know what else I might look at.

Comment: Can you compare the properties on the message on the static port vs the Dynamic send port?

Comment: No, the static port lets you set the "Transaction Supported" to false, which allows it to go through. The dynamic port only has on setting, and that's for setting up adapters.

Comment: So what is stopping you using Static ports?  How many different queues do you need to write to?

Comment: At this time I don't know, still waiting on the specs from the client. I tend to be tenacious. If the software says I can do it.. I'm gonna do it... haha

Comment: I have answered this on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70281133/i-have-a-biztalk-application-with-a-dynamic-send-port-that-is-set-to-mqseries

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question on this post: [I have a BizTalk application with a dynamic send port that is set to "MQSeries". Can I programmatically set its properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70281133/i-have-a-biztalk-application-with-a-dynamic-send-port-that-is-set-to-mqseries)

Basically, I had to create a copy of my message, and add the MQSeries.dll as a reference to my project. I then I set the property like this.

```
  DBMSGMQ = DBMSGOUT;
  DBMSGMQ(MQSeries.TransactionSupported)="False";
```