# I have a BizTalk application with a dynamic send port that is set to "MQSeries". Can I programmatically set its properties?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, biztalk

I have several projects in BizTalk that send messages to MQ. They error unless I set the MQSeries Transport property "Transactions Supported" to false, to get the message posted on MQ. Is there a way to modify MQSeries properties within my orchestration?

Comment: I suspect you're going to need to tell us a little bit more than that. Do you want to solve the Transactions Supported problem? Or are you just hoping to work around it by modifying properties for another application and leave that alone for the existing ones?

Comment: @MoragHughson  See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70202710/error-encountered-on-opening-queue-manager-name-reason-code-2354

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the schema MQSeries.MQSPropertySchema in BizTalk.System, there is an element TransactionSupported that is a string.  So that property should be available.  It is also documented MQSeries Adapter Properties, [Properties Related to BizTalk Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/properties-related-to-biztalk-server), and that the default is Yes.

[image]

> TransactionSupported  string  The adapter begins a Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) transaction between BizTalk Server and MQSeries Server. When set to No, there is no guarantee of message delivery.

Default: Yes

```
    <xs:element default="yes" name="TransactionSupported" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <b:fieldInfo propSchFieldBase="MessageContextPropertyBase" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" propertyGuid="A52D5930-5197-42d8-83AD-F732243D1B62" /> 
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks, curious where this schema is located? I assume as an IBM file? Directory path?

Comment: Thanks for the help..  I knew with some digging I'd find the solution. See my answer below.

Comment: @jamestreinen  I've added the location of the schema to the answer.  No, not an IBM file, this is a native properties file for BizTalk.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the TransactionSupported property inside my orchestration, and when I ran it, each message posted to the dynamic MQQueue name I extracted from a message attribute.

Code to set the property: (Inside of a construct message.)
First I created a new message of the same type.

```
DBMSGMQ = DBMSGOUT;
DBMSGMQ(MQSeries.TransactionSupported)="False";
```

Then inside an Expression shape:
[image]

My original message:
[image]

One last thing. MQSeries.dll has to be added as a reference to the orchestration.